# How to get the critical values of t statistics for alpha and beta in a restricted VECM in R?

Tags: r

We have a data frame that contains the variables (greenhouse gas emission, no. of cars per person, percentage of LPG-fueled cars among all cars)

```
df <- data.frame(
        emission = c(4.66,4.93,5.22,5.63,5.51,5.57,5.56,5.88,5.97,5.81,5.90,6.07),
        carpp = c(0.1505125,0.1618598,0.1753534,0.1844976,0.1924772,0.1973057,0.2047611,0.2153194,0.2252293,0.2345578,0.2435042,0.2558408),
        LPG_p=c(8.000962,11.653062,12.839622,14.436235,16.536271,18.109585,19.699988,20.731286,21.426939,21.933524,22.099233,21.799780)
    )
rownames(df) <- 2004:2015
df
```

Hence, our data:

```
     emission     carpp     LPG_p
2004     4.66 0.1505125  8.000962
2005     4.93 0.1618598 11.653062
2006     5.22 0.1753534 12.839622
2007     5.63 0.1844976 14.436235
2008     5.51 0.1924772 16.536271
2009     5.57 0.1973057 18.109585
2010     5.56 0.2047611 19.699988
2011     5.88 0.2153194 20.731286
2012     5.97 0.2252293 21.426939
2013     5.81 0.2345578 21.933524
2014     5.90 0.2435042 22.099233
2015     6.07 0.2558408 21.799780
```

After all the three variables are found to be nonstationary via unit root tests, the cointegration analysis

```
library(urca)
summary(ca.jo(df, K=2,type="trace", ecdet="none", spec="transitory"))
```

revealed that the three series are cointegrated with the rank r=1.

The following code **(** Verena Brufatto, 2015, "Macroeconomic Factors and the U.S. Stock Market Index: A Cointegration Analysis", MS Thesis, p.99; and many other sources as well **)** produces alfa, beta, t-statistics for alfa and beta:

```
V1.trace <- ca.jo(df, K=2,type="trace", ecdet="none", spec="transitory") # rank=1
vecm <- cajorls(V1.trace, r=1)
beta <- V1.trace@V[,1]
alfa <- V1.trace@W[,1]     
residuals <- resid(vecm$rlm)
N <- nrow(residuals) # 10
sigma <- crossprod(residuals)/N     
beta.se <- sqrt(diag(kronecker(solve(crossprod(V1.trace@RK[,-1])), solve(t(alfa)%*%solve(sigma) %*% alfa))))     
beta.t <- c(NA, beta[-1]/beta.se)     
alfa.se <- sqrt(solve(crossprod(cbind(V1.trace@ZK %*%beta, V1.trace@Z1)))[1,1]*diag(sigma))     
alfa.t <- alfa/alfa.se
```

Estimated cointegration normalized eigenvector matrix, alfa weights (loading matrix), t statistics from the above code:

```
    emission_(t-1)  carpp_(t-1) LPG_p_(t-1)
β              1    -17.8569153 -0.0374754
                   (-15.487457) (-5.406585)
α   -0.20755093     -0.01069378   2.76252149
   (-0.8393556)     (-7.4775057)  (16.0376516)
```

t-values are in paranthesis.

Assume that at this stage, we wanna find critical values of t-statistics for α and β. How can we find those?

**What I did:**
**1.** The following:

```
coeftest(cajorls(ca.jo(df, K=2,type="trace", ecdet="none", spec="transitory"), r=1)$rlm)
```

produces:

```
t test of coefficients:    
                           Estimate  Std. Error t value  Pr(>|t|)    
emission.d:ect1         -2.0754e-01  3.4970e-01 -0.5935  0.578678    
emission.d:constant     -1.4452e-01  4.6887e-01 -0.3082  0.770334    
emission.d:emission.dl1 -1.1461e-01  5.3116e-01 -0.2158  0.837695    
emission.d:carpp.dl1     4.3285e+01  3.3596e+01  1.2884  0.253999    
emission.d:LPG_p.dl1     9.8103e-02  9.9322e-02  0.9877  0.368642    
carpp.d:ect1            -1.0694e-02  2.0225e-03 -5.2874  0.003225 ** 
carpp.d:constant         1.6675e-02  2.7117e-03  6.1495  0.001653 ** 
carpp.d:emission.dl1     1.2156e-02  3.0719e-03  3.9570  0.010775 *  
carpp.d:carpp.dl1        1.9572e-01  1.9430e-01  1.0073  0.360017    
carpp.d:LPG_p.dl1        2.2761e-03  5.7442e-04  3.9625  0.010716 *  
LPG_p.d:ect1             2.7625e+00  2.4359e-01 11.3406 9.324e-05 ***
LPG_p.d:constant        -1.5706e+00  3.2660e-01 -4.8088  0.004846 ** 
LPG_p.d:emission.dl1    -9.8081e-01  3.7000e-01 -2.6509  0.045380 *  
LPG_p.d:carpp.dl1       -6.6548e+01  2.3402e+01 -2.8437  0.036091 *  
LPG_p.d:LPG_p.dl1       -1.7219e-01  6.9186e-02 -2.4888  0.055240 .  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Though alfa values are the same for `coeftest(cajorls(ca.jo()))` and above code, t-statistics are different.

2. I re-worked the same example in JMulti and got the following:
   (I wanna obtain what JMulti (or more true one) find)
   [image]

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I cannot help but you should provide the names of the packages that you use and maybe add them as key words.

Comment: @Gilles, I used the urcaurcaurca package that is standard in these kind of apps. Added to the above codes. Keyword adding requires 1500 reps.